# Reach out to Instagram about outsourcing their customer support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

I need to utilize the Instagram API for a client's website.
There's no way for me to log into the account I created a while ago, and there's no way to register a new account using my web browser. I searched around for support and found a Google Group that Instagram used, except that nobody can post on it anymore and there's the following notice:

> This Group will shut down soon. Please check the new support page on the developer site for more information: http://instagram.com/developer/support/

So I go to that URL, and find links to their blog (useless in my situation), a bug tool (again, not applicable), and the following:

> ### Community
>
> The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code. Make sure to tag your questions with the Instagram tag to get fast answers from other fellow developers.

However, on Stack Overflow, I find that most questions similar to my own are closed with comments along the lines of *"This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't Instagram's customer support."*

So, Instagram is being cheap by not providing any legitimate outlets for developer support, and Stack Overflow doesn't want to accept what should be Instagram's responsibility. As a developer, I am left with no options and no way to explain the situation to my client without looking like a dunce.

Comment: I'm confused about what action you're asking here.  Are you asking that SO ask Instagram to "knock it off" or are you asking that SO change it's attitude towards Instagram questions?

Comment: What was your question? I don't see any Instagram related questions on your user profile. If you were asking about programming against their API, it should probably be allowed (obviously depending on other qualifications for being on topic)

Comment: "*I need to utilize the Instagram API for a client's website. There's no way for me to log into the account I created a while ago, and there's no way to register a new account using my web browser.*" I don't see this as something that Instagram would try to off-load onto [sp]. Help with their programming APIs, sure, but not problems with logging into your Instagram developer account.

Comment: "*The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code. Make sure to tag your questions with the Instagram tag to get fast answers from other fellow developers.*" If Instagram is off-loading programming assistance onto [so], then *yes*, [se] staff should probably get in touch with them and make sure that Instagram questions are following Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: Yes, this is causing some Instagram API developers to believe SO is their support. So I believe that SE should reach out to them.

Comment: "The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code." -> I don't read this as Instagram suggesting you ask for account-recovery on SO.

Comment: @Blorgbeard you're right, that correlation isn't strong, but the error I received when trying to recover my password told me to "contact support" and the link to SO is the most relevant method of "support" mentioned on their website. The one exception is a somewhat hidden bug reporting form on Facebook's website.

Comment: I just looked over the last month's questions in [instagram] and aside from a handful of poorly researched questions, didn't see any indication that this tag was being abused. It's certainly a lot better than [facebook] ever was, and doesn't seem to be as bad as others who have directed traffic here.

Comment: @Qwertman I think I've read some stories recently (last month or two) on Hacker News about Instagram support going down the drain ever since they were acquired by Facebook...

Comment: @BradLarson, that's good to know, actually - this isn't quite as hot-button as some similar situations. I think, though, that it's good to have on record all instances of this sort of outsourcing. While Instagram isn't intentionally putting account support on SO's shoulders, they aren't providing their own outlet for that sort of support. For a company, outsourcing *some* support to SO might become a slippery slope, which sets a bad precedent.

Comment: `postmaster@instagram.com` `support@instagram.com` `admin@instagram.com` I'd bet you that someone gets that email :)

Comment: @Cupcake then someone should contact google: https://www.dartlang.org/support/

Comment: I don't think Dart counts. They're referencing SO for "general how-to" which is appropriate. They have dedicated channels for bugs and customer service, they're not trying to relegate that to SO like Instagram is (or was, haven't checked recently).