# TypeScriptLang.org redirecting to Stack Overflow as "forums"

Tags: discussion, product-support

On the front page of [TypeScriptLang.org](http://www.TypeScriptLang.org), there is a link marked "Forums".  Clicking this link brings you to Stack Overflow, to all questions tagged [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript).

This one's a little different than most of the "support" links companies try to foist off on us, as the description next to the link reads:

> Great place to get help with using TypeScript.

...which we are.  But calling us "Forums" feels wrong, and it feels like it sets the wrong tone for future interaction with the site (because we're not forums, not geared toward discussion as such).

Is this something we need to worry about?  I think I'd be happier if, at minimum, instead of `"Forums"`, it said something like `"Stuck? Having trouble implementing something?  Get great answers in TypeScript on Stack Overflow."`.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277810/ie-web-development-support-moving-to-stack-overflow

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow

Comment: AeroX has provided some fantastic links. The top answer in the second one tells you the proper course of action: "If the referring company did not give you clear guidance as to what types of questions would be a good fit for Stack Overflow, [contact the community team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) and let them know." So posting on Meta isn't the appropriate course of action here. Although we do appreciate the effort to keep StackOverflow a nice place. =)

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, perhaps I misunderstood your intent in the context of other comments. Also, I think you may have edited your comment while I was writing mine, and I didn't notice. Reply retracted, with apologies.

Comment: @IMSoP I edit my comments a lot, so probably so. Sorry. =) I might've accidentally hit Enter before I was done, too, and then edited rather than deleting and reposting.

Comment: I changed the text on the typescriptlang.org website to "Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is not very clear why you posted this here, there's little that SE or meta users can do about the language an external website uses.  One of the top rated SO users in the [typescript] tag is a Microsoft employee, Ryan Cavanaugh, you could perhaps add a comment to one of his posts to direct him here.

I speculate that it might be a left-over when it still directed to the MSDN Forums, most definitely *not* a great place to find help.

It is otherwise a *very* healthy tag, I follow it.  I see consistently good Q+A with a healthy set of experts posting great answers.  And questioners that understand the SO ways.  Beyond Ryan, the two other users that have a lot of posts are both book authors.  Nothing I see that needs to be fixed.

Comment: "the MSDN Forums, most definitely not a great place to find help." -- so sad, so true

Comment: I've multiple times seen this sort of thing posted at Meta; I always thought that was because SE would (occasionally) contact the site owners directly (and thus this is the right place to post).

Comment: @Joe See AeroX's second link and my comment on this question.

Comment: Re "not clear why you posted this here", take a look at [this search for "reach out to"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22reach+out+to%22) - it may not be the *best* way of raising this topic, but it's hardly a *surprising* one.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I'd seen similar questions to this one here before.  If nobody's called them yet, I will.

Comment: Apologies for the delay as this is the first I've seen of this thread; thanks @Shog9 for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 14):

I definitely don't want to give the impression that we (the TypeScript team or even me personally) think of Stack Overflow as a "forum" or an offloading/outsourcing of our responsibility to provide good support for our product.

Would changing the link on the website from "Forum" to "Stack Overflow" be the best course of action? There are obvious constraints in terms of the size of text we can fit into the link in that menu, but Stack Overflow really is a top-notch place for *questions* and I'd like to make sure people can find it easily.

**Edit:** Done!

Comment: "Support" might be more generic, descriptive, and applicable, though that's just an idle thought.

Comment: `"Stack Overflow"` probably works, yeah.  @Emrakul, I think `"Support"` would probably be _worse_, and would push the implication the opposite direction from what we want.