# Are "Microsoft-Cognitive" support questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

A recent question (I'll add a link if requested) asks about problems with response times of Microsoft Cognitive Services. I'm not familiar with this, and it's not immediately obvious whether this is a problem with the asker's own site, or a global services site provided by Microsoft. In either case, it reads as a "help desk" request, not a "programming problem".

I initially flagged as off-topic, with a comment that it would probably be best to ask the question on a Microsoft support site. The OP replied that they were "asked by the azure support to post this on SO".

From a brief search on Meta, there seems to be *some* acceptance of Microsoft farming-out their support to SO ([this question on sending Web Development questions to SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277810/2096401)), but the arguments there were that only "programming" questions should be asked, whereas this seems to be a "service quality" question that is (probably) nothing to do with programming.

So: should such questions be flagged (and is "off-topic" the best flag), and/or downvoted, or does the quasi-relationship with Microsoft mentioned in the link mean such questions should be left alone?

Comment: No, a "relationship" with Microsoft doesn't affect the standing rules regarding the site's scope and what is off-topic. You evaluate the question(s) on their own merits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the Microsoft Cognitive Services, but sometimes it's not the service that doesn't answer well, but the query which isn't well formed, like in SQL.

So if the question is about to optimize/change the query to a better one, it's on topic, if it's because the OP has a slow network, it's not.

Comment: The impression from the question is that it's the latter. I'll let the off-topic flag do it's work then.

Answer (score 3):

Programming-related questions under that tag are fine, but actual customer support questions do not belong here. Someone might want to reach out to the team at Microsoft responsible for this:

> We were asked by the azure support to post this on SO.

Or better, reach out to Microsoft in general, because this seems to happen more often lately.