# Instagram is *still* using Stack Overflow as a support forum

Tags: discussion

In 2014, a user asked if we could [Reach out to Instagram about outsourcing their customer support to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263148/reach-out-to-instagram-about-outsourcing-their-customer-support-to-stack-overflo). At the time, Brad Larson concluded:

> I just looked over the last month's questions in [instagram] and aside from a handful of poorly researched questions, didn't see any indication that this tag was being abused. It's certainly a lot better than [facebook] ever was, and doesn't seem to be as bad as others who have directed traffic here.

Fast-forward to today.

I voted to close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154638/our-instagram-app-pre-dates-account-linking-but-now-we-need-to-re-submit-for-ap and the user responded:

> Instagram has said their support looks for Stack Overflow comments tagged "instagram". Their website provides no contact information. I've tweeted at them and sent Facebook messages. So this is a desperation attempt.

Checking [[instagram]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) shows quite a few (un-answered, un-closed) questions that would be more properly addressed to Instagram support:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146080/instagram-bot-remove-sand-boxing-of-developer-client
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000946/starting-a-new-submission-for-an-extra-instagram-permission
- [oAuth.RequestToken(code) in instasharp does not work and returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991566/oauth-requesttokencode-in-instasharp-does-not-work-and-returns-null)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999884/bug-on-specific-instagram-video
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958156/how-get-instagram-approved-api

And that's just in the last few days. [[instagram-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) is also pretty bad for this kind of question.

So allow me to re-propose: someone at Stack Exchange should reach out to Instagram and ask them to please stop using us as their support forum -- or, at the very least, *answer the questions from their users*.

See also [Do any companies have agreements with Stack Overflow to use the site as a support channel? What's the best course of action if not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256088/do-any-companies-have-agreements-with-stack-overflow-to-use-the-site-as-a-suppor), [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: You can't control what users actually do and where they ask their question.  Is Instragram actually sending user to SO (do you have evidence other than that user's comment, I mean(?  If so, then that's the issue that should be dealt with, not ignorant users asking in the wrong spot.  Those should be dealt with like any other off-topic or poor quality question.

Comment: "Is Instragram actually sending user to SO? If so, then that's the issue that should be dealt with, not ignorant users asking in the wrong spot." That is the entire goal of this question-proposal, yes.

Comment: I understand that - but my question for you is - did you confirm that Instagram is still sending users here?  Or are you taking that one user's word for it?  Reason I say that is [Instagram's support page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/) seems to suggest they are handling it correctly.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I can't confirm what the user is saying without registering for an account -- their support page links solely to a Tumblr blog, and their developer dashboard requires logging in.

Comment: Generally speaking, per the posts you linked, companies are allowed to suggest users ask **development** related questions on SO, they just can't out-source their entire support community here.  Just as the answer on the post you linked suggests and my answer suggests, they aren't doing anything wrong. They are just suggesting SO as a place for development questions.  Instagram can't and shouldn't be responsible for users who decide that they need to ask support questions here since they do provide a proper place for them to report issues.

Comment: OK, you've convinced me. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am reading [Instagram's developer support](https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/) page.  The entire text of that page reads:

> ## Developer Support
>
> ### Blog
>
> The Developer Blog features news and important announcements about the Instagram Platform. You will also find tutorials and best practices to help you build great platform integrations. Make sure to subscribe to the RSS feed not to miss out on new posts: http://developers.instagram.com.
>
> ### Report Issue
>
> The Developer Dashboard allows you to report issues you find with the Instagram developer platform by clicking on the Report Issue button. When submitting a report, please be as clear and concise as possible and make sure to include the exact steps or code to reproduce the bug. As developers you understand that the better you can detail the issue, the quicker we can locate and resolve it. We are here to knock these down, so help us help you!
>
> ### Community
>
> The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code. Make sure to tag your questions with the Instagram tag to get fast answers from other fellow developers.

They have a channel to report issues and still provide announcements via their blog, they are only pointing users to SO to help with their API related questions, which are entirely on-topic.  Just because users are posting low-quality questions on SO does not mean Instagram is sending them here intentionally for off-topic questions, nor should the SO team need to reach out to them as they aren't doing anything wrong.

The users who are posting terrible questions needs to be dealt with individually by downvoting and/or voting to close the questions as appropriate.